# Explanation of a part of the FTC proof from Elementary Analysis Ross

Tags: real-analysis

In the second edition of Elementary Analysis by Ross the second part of the FTC is given as:

Let f be an integrable function on $[a,b]$. For $ x \in [a,b]$, let $$F(x) = \int_{a}^{b} f(t)dt.$$ If f is continuous at $x_0 \in (a,b)$, then F is differentiable at $x_0$ and $F'(x_0) = f(x_0)$.

The proof is given as follows:

Choose $B > 0$ such that $|f(x)| < B$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$. If $x,y \in [a,b]$ and $|x-y| < \frac{\epsilon}{B}$ where $x < y$, then $$|F(y) - F(y)| = |\int_{x}^{y}f(t)dt| \leq \int_{x}^{y}|f(t)dt| \leq \int_{x}^{y}Bdt = B(y-x) < \epsilon \implies$$ $|F(y) - F(x)| < \epsilon$ $\implies$ $F$ is uniformly continuous at $x_0 \in (a,b)$. Suppose $f$ is continuous at $x_0 \in (a,b)$

$$\frac{F(x) - F(x_0)}{x - x_0} = \frac{1}{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t)dt$$ and $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t)dt$$ And so, $$\frac{F(x) - F(x_0)}{x - x_0} - f(x) = \frac{1}{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^{x}[f(t) - f(x_0)]dt\ ... (1)$$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $t \in (a,b)$ and $|t - x_0| < \delta$ imply $|f(t) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$

Then the book says that it follows from (1) that, $$|\frac{F(x) - F(x_0)}{x - x_0} - f(x_0)| \leq \epsilon$$ Can someone explain how that follows from (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
$$
\frac{F(x) - F(x_0)}{x - x_0} - f(x_0) = \frac{1}{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^{x}[f(t) - f(x_0)]dt\ ... (1)
$$
where I've replaced the $f(x)$ on the left iwth $f(x_0)$, which is what it should be.

Now put absolute values around everything: 
\begin{align}
|\frac{F(x) - F(x_0)}{x - x_0} - f(x_0)| 
&= |\frac{1}{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^{x}[f(t) - f(x_0)]dt|\\
&= |\frac{1}{x-x_0}| \cdot |\int_{x_0}^{x}[f(t) - f(x_0)]dt|
\end{align}
Now the right hand integrand is no more than $\epsilon$, so we get
\begin{align}
|\frac{F(x) - F(x_0)}{x - x_0} - f(x_0)| 
&\le |\frac{1}{x-x_0}| \cdot |\int_{x_0}^{x}\epsilon dt|\\
&\le |\frac{1}{x-x_0}| \cdot |x - {x_0}|\epsilon \\
&= \epsilon 
\end{align}

Comment: Why is the integrand on the right-hand no more than $\epsilon$? Edit: Nevermind I saw why

Answer (score 0):

From $|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$  for $|x-x_0|<\delta$, you have$\int_{x_0}^x|f(x)-f(x_0)|dx< \int_{x_0}^x\epsilon dx < \epsilon|x-x_0|$.